# Problems with 2nd HDD in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I just made the switch to Lubuntu and was a previous Ubuntu 12.04 user but preferred the slimmed down profile of Lubuntu. I added a second hdd and it shows up as mounted but won't let me access the files on it saying I don't have permission and in qBittorrent it won't show up as an option for where to send my downloads.

Comment: Daniel, could you add the outputs of the following two commands please?

`df -h`
`sudo fdisk -l`